# Can Google Daydream View function as a Cardboard for unsupported phones?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7, google-cardboard, daydream-vr

I have the $79 I need to buy a Daydream View, but not the $650 to buy a Pixel to go along with it. My current phone is a Galaxy S7. (Don't tell me to just get a Gear VR. That's not what I'm asking.) If I get a Daydream View for my Galaxy S7, or any other phone that doesn't come with built-in Daydream support, will I be able to just use it like a really fancy Cardboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprised this hasn't been answered - but yes, Cardboard is just to hold your phone and have basic lenses to view the split screen. Daydream VR is a superset of that functionality, so Cardboard apps should work fine with it.

Comment: Thanks! In hindsight I think the goofy original title was why it went unanswered for so long. I forgot that this isn't Arqade and silly misleading titles aren't the norm.